# Matplotlib workflow

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am working on a school project, and I'm using matplotlib to plot all my plots, but I find it very tedious to copy the first plot and then just change the variable name to add other plots (subplots).

You can see how I have done it on this link:

[IPython Project Notebook](https://github.com/joddm/Project/blob/master/TEK-3002%20Rel.ipynb)

I would greatly appreciate feedback on how to improve my workflow, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider isolating the plot-making mechanics into their own function, so you can make a `for` loop that calls that function for each variable.  Here's an example (I only replicated two of your parameter lists, but you can see how you'd add the rest).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols= 2, figsize=(10,10))
x = np.linspace(0,1000000,num=10000)

def plot_maker(ax, x, var, var_name, ax_x, ax_y):
    sh, l, sc = sts.weibull_min.fit(var, floc=0)
    y = sts.weibull_min.pdf(x, sh, l, sc)
    print('Weibull parameters for {0}:\n Scale: {1:2.2f}\n Shape: {2:02.2f}'.format(var_name, sc, sh))
    ax[ax_x, ax_y].hist(var, normed=True)
    ax[ax_x, ax_y].plot(x, y, 'r', lw=2)

params = [
    [fuel['TTF or TBF'], 'Fuel TBF', 0, 0],
    [engine['TBF(TTF)'], 'Engine TBF', 0, 1],
]

for param_list in params:
    var, var_name, ax_x, ax_y = param_list
    plot_maker(ax, x, var, var_name, ax_x, ax_y)
```

There are lots of ways to write this, but the important thing is that you separate modelling and plot-making from the individual parameters, so you can add arbitrary parameters as you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you do something like this, you can call your plotting function & just send it the axes you want to plot (using .reshpae(-1) allows you to flatten the axes) and a list of the variables you want to plot.  You can also send it list of other parameters like colours or subtitles.

```
def Plotter(axes,Yvars,Colors,x):
for ax, yvar, c in zip(axes,Yvars,Colors):
    ax.plot(x,yvar,color = c)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols= 2, figsize=(10,10))

Yvars = [y1,y2,y3,y4,y5]
Colors = ['b','b','g','g','r']
ax_to_plot = axes.reshape(-1)[0:5]
Plotter(ax_to_plot,Yvars,Colors,x)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: You should consider marking one of these answers as accepted since they both answer your question.